# working out what a conformal map does!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quasiconformal-maps

I am trying to work out what the following conformal maps do. The motivation for this is to know that what must the characteristics of lambda be so that resulting image is in the right half plane (we are investigating these maps in order to show the real part of something is positive), but I don't know where to begin!

\begin{equation}
  M_{\pm}^1 (\lambda) = \frac{1 \pm  \lambda }{(1 - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2)}
\end{equation}

Here is an example of one of the maps. I have considered splitting it into partial fractions to get the addition of two mobius transforms. But I wouldn't know how to consider this!

Kindest regards, 
Catherine

Comment: I would like to know what this does to the unit circle for instance!

Comment: You want the image of what to lie in $\Re(z) > 0$ ? For any finite length continuous closed curve you can find a rational function sending the unit circle $\epsilon$-approximately to that curve (think to Fourier series).

Comment: Can you elaborate on that answer? I haven't done complex analysis for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M(z) = (1 + z)/(1 - z^2/2)$; the other mapping is $M(-z)$. We have
$$\operatorname{Re} M(e^{i t}) =
\frac {2 (2 + \cos t - \cos 2 t)} {5 - 4 \cos 2 t},$$
therefore the image of the unit circle lies in the right half-plane, with the exception of $M(-1) = 0$. Next,
$$\operatorname{Re} M(u + i v) = -\frac
{2 (u^3 + u^2 + u (v^2 - 2) - v^2 - 2)}
{u^4 + 2 u^2 (v^2 - 2) + (v^2 + 2)^2}.$$
The denominator is positive unless $(u, v) = (\pm \sqrt 2, 0)$. The numerator gives an algebraic curve which has one unbounded component with the asymptote $u = 1$ and one bounded component in the left half-plane. The sign of the numerator changes when crossing the curve.

Comment: thank you so much! to get the image of the unit circle did you just let r=1 and then look at how t is varied? Are you considering what it does to lines in the first part and curves in the second part? x

Comment: The first part is for the unit circle, not the unit disk. $u$ and $v$ in the second part are arbitrary. The third-degree curve splits the plane into three regions; $\operatorname{Re} M$ is negative to the right of the unbounded component and in the interior of the bounded component. The unit circle has only one common point with one of the components, so the sign of $\operatorname{Re} M$ doesn't change inside the unit disk: https://i.imgur.com/yZ1ZorX.png.

Comment: Great thank you so much!

Comment: So you're saying that an arbitrary line is transformed to a curve. What is meant by the interior of the bounded component? It is a cubic graph so what is the bounded component bounded by?

Comment: A [cubic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_curve) can have a bounded component. (Actually, I should have said, the closed unit disk has only one common point with that component; a priori, it's possible for it to be touching the unit circle from the inside.)

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: How do you know that it is negative to the right of the asymptote and inside the bounded component? Also, what is the significance of the unit disk only touching once?

Comment: To the right of the curve, to be precise. Take large $z > 0$: $M(z)$ has a large positive numerator and a large negative denominator. We're not interested in where straight lines get mapped to; we want to find $(u, v)$ s.t. $\operatorname{Re} M(u + i v) = 0$. That condition defines a cubic curve that separates the plane into three regions; the sign of the real part changes every time the point $(u, v)$ moves from one region to another. Look at the picture in my first comment; imagine the small oval lying inside the unit disk.

Comment: Yes, the sign changes, but how do we know that inside the bounded region it is negative and outside of this is positive. etc? I can see the picture, but cannot tell how it is obvious from the equation what the negative and positive regions are. Thank you for all your help, I know my questions must be frustrating.

Comment: We know that $M(z) < 0$ for large $z > 0$ and $M(z) > 0$ for large $z < 0$. To verify that the sign of the real part indeed changes when crossing the oval, take any point inside the oval.

Comment: Thank you, and would we have to use python or something like this to get the sign in the oval? Or can we discover this analytically? For instance can we get an equation of an ellipse from the cubic curve?

Comment: The numerator of $\operatorname{Re} M(u + i v)$ is quadratic in $v$, so we're just solving $a v^2 + b > 0$.

Comment: Great thank you!